# Batch file fails when solution is built by Jenkis, but works when solution is built via command line

Tags: visual-studio-2012, batch-file, msbuild, jenkins

### The problem

I have a batch file the is being called from a Pre-Build event.
When the solution is being built by **Jenkins** it **fails**.
When the solution is being built from **MSBuild** or **visual studio** in command line It **works fine**.
My question is, what could cause such a behaviour?

### Details

In my solution (.Net 4.5 and C++ projects), I have a batch file that is called from one of the project's Pre-Build events.
It works fine, except when I am trying to build the solution via Jenkins (CI Server). 
The error is :

> The command ""C:\Jenkins\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\jobs\Builld_SMW2\workspace\Autosync\CopySymAlignFiles.bat" "C:\Jenkins\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\jobs\Builld_SMW2\workspace\" "C:\Jenkins\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\jobs\Builld_SMW2\workspace\Autosync\" "Debug"" exited with code 1.

from the error report, I copied the command that was used for attempting to build the solution:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Platform=x86 /p:configuration=Debug /t:Rebuild /verbosity:quiet /p:WarningLevel=0 /p:Platform=x86 /p:configuration=Debug /t:Rebuild /verbosity:quiet /p:WarningLevel=0 ..\SMW2_Analysis.sln

(I am aware that the arguments are being passed twice, I have no Idea why jenkins does that, but this is not the issue...)

If I run this command from command line, the batch file works fine once the build event is triggered.

The content of CopySymAlignFiles.bat is:

> Echo off
>   set solutionDir=%1
>   set projectDir=%2
>   set configuration=%3
>
> REM Removing quotes
>   set solutionDir=%solutionDir:"=%
>   set projectDir=%projectDir:"=%
>   set configuration=%configuration:"=%
>
> REM Does strings have a trailing slash? if so remove it
>   IF %solutionDir:~-1%==\ SET solutionDir=%solutionDir:~0,-1%
>   IF %projectDir:~-1%==\ SET projectDir=%projectDir:~0,-1%
>   IF %configuration:~-1%==\ SET configuration=%configuration:~0,-1%
>
> REM This is just for easier debugging
>   Echo Solution Directory is: "%solutionDir%"
>   Echo Project Directory is: "%projectDir%"
>   Echo Configuration directory is: "%configuration%"
>   Echo Current Directory is: "%CD%"
>   Echo The batch file is executed at "%~dp0"
>
> REM Copying sym_align files
>   copy /Y "%solutionDir%\SymAlignGlue\sym_align.dll" "%projectDir%"
>   copy /Y "%solutionDir%\SymAlignGlue\sym_align.ctf" "%projectDir%"
>
> set isPV=%configuration%=="PV Release"
>   IF  %isPV% copy /Y "%solutionDir%\SymAlignGlue\Release\SymAlignGlue.dll" "%projectDir%"
>   IF NOT %isPV%  copy /Y "%solutionDir%\SymAlignGlue\%configuration%\SymAlignGlue.dll" "%projectDir%"
>
> REM The result...
>   IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
>   REM Success
>     Echo Copied SymAlign files.
>     exit /b 0
>   )
>   IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0  (
>   REM Error
>     Echo An error was found while Copied SymAlign files. Error level was %ERRORLEVEL%
>     exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
>   )

**Some additional Information:**

1. I am running Jenkins as a service and I have the service logon as An Administrator.

Does Anyone have an Idea how can this happen?

Comment: when running as a service there's some things that don't work afaik like access to mapped drives etc. Might that be the problem? Also since you're using msbuild anyway, I'd write that batch file in msbuild, it will only take about half the lines for the same functionality

Comment: @stijn I is not a Mapped drive issue, everything is on a local hard disk. What do you mean by  "write that batch file in msbuild"?

Comment: create an msbuild script that does the same as a batch file and call that. It will be shorter and more readable. But that's just a suggestion, likely won't solve anything. Can you try to get more logging or so? are the `echo` statements from the batch file shown properly in the Jenkins output?

Comment: The Echo are not showing in Jenkins log. I have tried also to write to the event log, with no success either.

Comment: @stijn I was able to log to event log, and it seems that the last copy fails. I will look into it... Thanks for your comments!

Comment: another point: when working with batch files in it's a good idea to prefix your variables (eg yyProjectDir/yySolutionDir) or unset them at the end of the batch file: names like projectDir and solutionDir are very common and for example used by msbuild. Which means if you first run a batchfile which sets projectDir and then call msbuild, things might get messy.

Comment: @stijn Wow! you have read my computer's mind. This was another issue I was facing. I rarely use batch files and did not think about the difference of variables scope in compare to C#. So what is the scope of a variable that was created in a batch file? it is there until the process dies? Thanks again!

Comment: Normally the scope is for the process the batch file runs in. So suppose you are on a command line and invoke the batch file above, then after it exits 'projectDir' etc are still in the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it seems that the issue was that there was a duplicate workspace folder.
1 was updated, and the other 1 was built, resulting the tested workspace did not get latest updates.
according to [this link](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Repo-cloned-twice-in-multi-config-job-td3799293.html) this was due to the way jenkins behaves with multiple configurations.